# “X_FORWARDED_FOR” Header Doesn't Present In The Request

Tags: proxy, tomcat

In my web application I need to extract the real ip address for clients behind proxy, after searching I found that the possible method to do that is to read the content of "X_FORWARDED_FOR" header , I am using java servlet and the headers of the incoming request doesn't contain "X_FORWARDED_FOR" header , So why the header doesn't included in the request?

I am using java 1.7 , tomcat v7 , proxy server :TMG and configured to use "X_FORWARDED_FOR" header .

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your tomcat configuration where XFF is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMG doesn't support X-Forwarded-For out of the box; you need to add a third party web filter such as [Winfrasoft X-Forwarded-For for TMG](http://www.winfrasoft.com/products/X-Forwarded-For/) to gain this capability in your TMG reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

The Winfrasoft one is 4,500 per server.  Try a free, open source one:

https://github.com/ramonsmits/XFF-Filter4TMG